# Как проверить существуют ли объекты с похожими данными? Элементарный C#

Tags: c#, классы, словари, конструктор

```csharp
class Account
{

    public double Sum { get; set; } 

    public int ID { get; set; }

    public Account(int id, double sum)
    {
        //if (valuesAreFuckedUp)
        //{
        //    exeption bla bla lba
        //}

        ID = id;
        Sum = sum;
    }
}
```

Суть в том, чтобы всякий созданный объект типа Account имел уникальный ID. Предполагаю что это необходимо делать в конструкторе.

Думаю, ключ к решению это Dictionary, где TKey будет ID объекта, а в качестве второго значения TValue сам объект. Проблема лишь в том, что я не знаю как занести объект в Dictionary сразу после создания.

Comment: Можно использовать GUID в качестве id.

Comment: Думаю, я еще слишком неопытный масляток для этого. Есть ли другие решения проблемы?

Comment: Можно использовать статическую переменную и увеличивать на один каждый раз. А её значение и будет id для нового объекта.

Comment: Так что надо-то? Уникальный ИД или "проверить существуют ли объекты с похожими данными"? Если первое - GUID, как выше сказали, второе - реализовать IComparable или GetHashValueю

Comment: Похоже текст вопроса, неправильно описывает суть, в описании вопроса я написал что я имел ввиду.

Comment: Айдишник должен быть уникальным локально - в каждом сеансе работы программы? Или глобально, даже после перезапуска программы? В последнем случае эти аккаунты где-то хранятся, а вот это хранилище (база данных) и должна заведовать уникальностью id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Я конечно запоздал, но разобрался-таки с вопросом. Видимо мой вопрос, оказался не совсем точным и были некоторые недопонимания от пользователей, но вот мой ответ на свой же вопрос. Итак, задача состояла в том, чтобы при создании объектов им нельзя было присвоить один и тот же ID(например) или другой параметр. Как я и предполагал для этого можно использовать Dictionary.

class Type
    {
        // Словарь, где ключ это ID объекта, а значение сам объект
        public static Dictionary<int, Type> idController = new Dictionary<int, Type>();

        public int ID { get; set; }

        public Type(int id)
        {
            ID = id;
            try
            {
                idController.Add(ID, this); //Добавляем в список созданный объект с его ID
            }
            catch (ArgumentException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Обнаружены объекты с совпадающим ID.");
            }
        }
    }

Если написать что-то вроде

var type1 = new Type(1);
var type2 = new Type(1);

вызовется блок catch и выведет "Обнаружены объекты с совпадающими ID."
```

Answer (score 1):

Как предложил @DanBear в комментариях, можно использовать статическое поле для задания уникального идентификатора. Само свойство `Id` при этом сделать только для чтения.

```csharp
class Account
{
    private static int _idCounter = 0;

    public double Sum { get; set; } 

    public int Id { get; private set; }

    public Account(double sum)
    {
        Id = _idCounter++;
        Sum = sum;
    }
}
```

А в словарь это можно внести вот так

```csharp
Dictionary<int, Account> accounts = new Dictionary<int, Account>();
Account account = new Account(1234);
accounts.Add(account.Id, account);
```